# How to create a Typescript/Javascript library within an Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, design-patterns

I want to create a library which is framework agnostic so that it can work with Angular/React/Vue or even in pure typescript project.
But I'm an Angular developer and I would like to create it within an Angular project to test it directly in a real usecase.
I saw that Angular can do it for us with its own cli : https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries

The problem is I have to code my library with Angular Components, Services and Modules and I want to avoid that (The code will be published to github).
How can I structure my project given my current constraints ?

Comment: you might want to be more specific about what you're doing because so far I can't see what the problem is or why you don't want to use Angular components while building it with Angular.  If you look into "micro frontends" you'll see that Angular, React and View all allow one to create something that can plug into anything, so it's kind of hard to understand what it is you "can't" do or envision a use case that outlines the challenge you're having.

Comment: I actually have a 2D diagramming project which has to be coded with Angular as I never learn neither React nor Vue. So, as my code could be reused I would like to create a library. I know I can create it with Angular CLI but I want that library could be published to npm registry as well for Angular projects as React or Vue projects. So, it should be framework agnostic and maybe the Angular library format can cause problems for consumers. Or angular library syntax is not a problem ?